# IndexError: string index out of range:

Tags: python, list, dictionary, range

I'm trying take a .txt file populated by 88 rows, each of which has two characters separated by a space, copy the first character in each row into a list #1, copy the second character of each list into a list #2 and then populate a dictionary with those two lists. Something, however, is going wrong when I try to copy down the data from the file into my lists. Could you tell me what I'm not doing correctly?

I keep getting this error: "IndexError: string index out of range" at the line where I have typed "column1[count] = readit[0]"

```
def main():

    modo = open('codes.txt', 'r')       #opening file
    filezise = 0                        #init'ing counter
    for line in modo:
        filezise+=1                     #counting lines in the file
    column1 = []*filezise
    column2 = []*filezise               #making the lists as large as the file
    count = 0                           #init'ing next counter
    while count < filezise+1:
        readit = str(modo.readline())
        column1[count] = readit[0]      ##looping through the file and
        column2[count] = readit[2]      ##populating the first list with the
        count+=1                        #first character and the second list       
    print(column1, column2)             #with the second character     
    index = 0                               
    n = 0
    codebook = {}                       #init'ing dictionary
    for index, n in enumerate(column1): #looping through to bind the key
        codebook[n] = column2[index]    #to its concordant value
    print(codebook)
main()
```

Comment: readit is a string, not a list.

Comment: @Marichyasana, I think he knows that but he can still index into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
 for line in modo:
        filezise+=1
```

You have already consumed the file.
If you want to consume it again, you need to do `modo.seek(0)` first to rewind the file back.

If you do not rewind the file, the line below will return an empty string, because there is nothing left in the file.

```
readit = str(modo.readline())
```

Of course, there's no real need to go through the file twice. You can just do it once and append to your lists.

```
column1 = []
column2 = []
for line in modo:
   filezise+=1
   column1.append(line[0])
   column2.append(line[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
codebook =  dict([''.join(line.strip().split(' ')) for line in open('codes.txt').readlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `column1 = []*filezise` doesn't actually make a list of length filezise. (If you look at the result, you will see that `column1` is just an empty list.) When you try to access `column1[count]` when `count > 0`, you will get that error because there is nothing in `column1` with an index greater than 0.

You shouldn't be trying to initialize the list. Instead, iterate over the lines in the file and append the appropriate characters:

```
column1=[]
column2=[]
for line in file('codes.txt'):
    column1.append(line[0])
    column2.append(line[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to get a dictionary from your file, by using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and the [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) built-in function:

```
import csv

with open('codes.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    codebook = dict(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as the intermediate lists aren't being used, you could also use a dictionary comprehension to do everything in one go.

```
with open('codes.txt', 'r') as f:
    codebook = {line[0]: line[-1] for line in f.read().splitlines()}
```